# Facebook Share Dialog "The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains." within a chrome extension

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to use Facebook's Javascript SDK to allow users to content from a chrome extension. I'd like to prompt the user with the share dialog.

Unfortunately, because this is from a chrome extension and can be on any domain whenever I try to share anything I get the error "The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains.". This is because I'd need to list all domains in the app domains setting.

Anyone know of a possible workaround?  Thanks!

Comment: Did you try turning off the "Strict Mode" for Facebook development? See this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/12/18/strict-uri-matching/).

Comment: @Mr.Rebot the option to turn this off doesn’t exist any more for newly created apps.

Comment: Workaround 1) Get your extension to show a page from your domain somehow, and trigger it from there. Workaround 2) Use the URL Redirect version of the Share or Feed dialog, then you can specify the redirect_uri to either go to your app’s domain, or specify a Facebook URL as the target (you’d have to check if the latter still works, it used to.)